# Is there any documentation for the "microsoft-edge-holographic" and the "ms-xbl-3d8b930f" uri protocols?

Tags: windows, uri, microsoft-edge

Is there any documentation for the "microsoft-edge-holographic" and the "ms-xbl-3d8b930f" URI protocols?
I am looking for some information about these two URIs and I can't seem to be able to find even an example of how to use them.

Any help, documentation, or example would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Felix, can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do in your application. I think that will help get a good answer to solve the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find official doc about them. I only find [this blog](https://www.hexacorn.com/blog/2018/06/25/url-schemes-in-win-10/) which contains these two uri schemes. They both open Edge when I click them. They're used like this:

```
microsoft-edge-holographic://
```

```
ms-xbl-3d8b930f://
```

Comment: Sadly I would like something more technical, such as the parameters.

Comment: Almost no other information about them can be found online. But I think the usage of them is like `microsoft-edge` protocol. Let's wait to see if there're other community members have other information.

Comment: @yu zhou Nobody's speaking up